# simple C++ basic factory pattern failing

Tags: c++11

I am new to c++ and am trying a basic factory pattern in C++11 but is failing with  error: 'X' does not refer to a value.
Any suggestions?

Test Code:
    X instance = X.createNewInstance();

Original Class

```
class X
{
public:

    static X createNewInstance() {
        return X();
    };


    void foo() ;

private:

    X(){};

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call static member functions with `::`

```
X instance = X::createNewInstance();
```